# How do I select 32-bit Java for use by any browser on my Mac?

Tags: macos, java

I would like to use a banking application in my browser. When I try to run it, I get this dialog box:

> It appears you are using 64-bit Java. This system is designed for
>   32-bit Java only. Please use 32-bit browser (Windows), or select
>   32-bit Java (MAC).

It doesn't matter whether I use Chrome, Firefox, or Safari, I get the same eror. How can I make this run on any of these browsers? (One is enough.)

I am using:

- Mac OS 10.6.8
- Chrome 16.0.912.75
- Firefox 7.0.1
- Safari 5.1.2

Comment: First thing, make sure you're using the latest verison: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1421

Comment: Can a 64-bit browser instantiate a 32-bit JRE on OS X?  You might need to make sure your browser is running in 32-bit mode, which (IIRC)  can be done from it's properties window (e.g. "Get Info").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Finder menu:

```
Go - > Utilities -> Java Preferences
```

Make sure you have both versions checked and drag them in the order you want them to be loaded. In your case, drag the 32-bit version to the top (opposite of mine).

[image]